# Find closest date in one query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently trying to figure out a way to find the closest date of a entry in mongoDB to the on i'm looking for.

Currently i solved the problem by using 2 queries. One using $gte and limit(1) to look for the next larger date and then $lte - limit(1) to see if there is a closer on that might be lower.

I was wondering, if there might be a way to find the closest date in just one query, but was not able to find anything on that matter.

Hope you can help me with this, or at least tell me for sure that this is the only way to do so.

```
db.collection.find({"time":{$gte: isoDate}}).sort({"time":1}).limit(1)
db.collection.find({"time":{$lte: isoDate}}).sort({"time":-1}).limit(1)
```

But I am looking for a way to do this in one query so i dont have to subtract the results to find the closest one.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some sample data, expected output and the query you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this one

```
db.collection.find({"time":{$gte: isoDate,$lt: isoDate}}).sort({"time":1}).limit(1)
```

Please use the same format what mongodb support like following

```
ISODate("2015-10-26T00:00:00.000Z")
```

Comment: Are you guys sure about this answer? When I run that query I don't get any documents returned. If I understand the query correctly, the $time property would need to both be less than and greater than or equal to isoDate which isn't possible.

Comment: @Shea thanks for asking the question, See this query will just look into the particular collection for any records which comes under the provided selected criteria.

Comment: I believe I understand the intention of the query, but I don't believe it is correct. The only way I have found retrieve the closest date with Mongo is via two queries as the original poster suggested.

Comment: I agree with previous comments. This answer will not yield any results id the date is the same. at least not in my tests and that makes total sense. For the correct way of doing it see OP

Comment: @Thom please post your db data, on which you are applying this query.

Comment: @AlokDeshwal This answer will not retrieve objects from the database and should be deleted.

Answer (score 6):

I solved a similar problem using an aggregation.

Sample data:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e365a1655c3f0bea76632a0"), 
  "time" : ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00Z"), 
  "description" : "record 1" 
}
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e365a1655c3f0bea76632a1"), 
  "time" : ISODate("2020-02-01T00:05:00Z"), 
  "description" : "record 2"
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e365a1655c3f0bea76632a2"), 
  "time" : ISODate("2020-02-01T00:10:00Z"), 
  "description" : "record 3"
}
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e365a1655c3f0bea76632a3"), 
  "time" : ISODate("2020-02-01T00:15:00Z"), 
  "description" : "record 4"
}
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e365a1655c3f0bea76632a4"), 
  "time" : ISODate("2020-02-01T00:20:00Z"), 
  "description" : "record 5"
}
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e365a1655c3f0bea76632a5"), 
  "time" : ISODate("2020-02-01T00:25:00Z"), 
  "description" : "record 6"
}
```

And I'm looking for the record nearest to ISODate('2020-02-01T00:18:00.000Z').

```
db.test_collection.aggregate([
{
    $match: 
        {
            time: 
                {
                    $gte: ISODate('2020-02-01T00:13:00.000Z'), 
                    $lte: ISODate('2020-02-01T00:23:00.000Z')
                }
        }
},
{
    $project:
        {
            time: 1,
            description: 1,
            time_dist: {$abs: [{$subtract: ["$time", ISODate('2020-02-01T00:18:00.000Z')]}]}}
},
{
    $sort: {time_dist: 1}
},
{
    $limit: 1
}])
```

The $match stage sets up a "time window". I used 5 minutes for this example.

The $project stage adds a time distance field. This is the time in milliseconds each record is from the query time of ISODate('2020-02-01T00:18:00.000Z').

Then I sorted on the time_dist field and limit the results to 1 to return the record with time closest to ISODate('2020-02-01T00:18:00.000Z').

The result of the aggregation:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e365a1655c3f0bea76632a4"), 
  "time" : ISODate("2020-02-01T00:20:00Z"), 
  "description" : "record 5", 
  "time_dist" : NumberLong(120000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

accourding to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33351918/4885936
don't need ISODate
simple easy  solution is:
if you want 1 hour left to due date just simply :

```
const tasks = await task.find({
      time: {
        $gt: Date.now(),
        $lt: Date.now() + 3600000 // one hour to miliseconds
      }
    })
```

this code get tasks from now to upcoming one hour later.

Answer (score -2):

In Pymongo, I used the following function. The idea is to take a `datetime` object, subtract some days from it and add some days to it, then find a date between those two dates. If there are no such records, increase the date span:

```py
import datetime, dateutil

def date_query(table, date, variance=1):
  '''Run a date query using closest available date'''
  try:
    date_a = date - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(days=variance)
    date_b = date + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(days=variance)
    result = db[table].find({'date': {'$gte': date_a, '$lt': date_b}}).sort([('date', 1)])
    result = list(result)
    assert len(result) >= 1
    return result[len(result)//2] # return the result closest to the center
  except:
    return date_query(table, date, variance=variance*2)
```